# referencing views elements in xcode iphone programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to do something really simple, but I can't find any examples and can't figure out.
I am coding in xcode 4 for iphone 5.

I have 2 views on my storyboard. One has a button (ButtonFromFirstView) which leads to my second view. The second view has a picker view object and a "select" button. When I click "select" it takes me to my first view. And I would like the ButtonFromFirstView title to be the string selected in the picker from second view. How do I get what value was selected in the picker view?

in my second view I have the following method which catches the changes in the picker. However ButtonFromFirstView is NOT available. How can I get to it? If the button is on the same view where picker is, that it works, but this is not what I want.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSString *SelectedString = [DeparturePickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [ButtonFromFirstView setTitle:SelectedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, you may be interested to know that the standard in Objective-C is camelCase for variables (`departurePickerArray`, `buttonFromFirstView`), and PascalCase for class names and constants (`UIPickerView`, `UIControlStateNormal`).

Answer (score 2):

The general paradigm for iOS development is that each "screenful" of content should have a separate view controller. So, for each of your two screens, you should have a subclass of UIViewController, rather than a subclass of UIView.

Your question is essentially - how do you pass information between the two view controllers? In a situation as simple as yours, the best way is to hook them up from your app delegate class. So when you create the view controllers (e.g. from a nib), you want to create a method which you call like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ... (create view controllers)

    [secondViewController setButtonToUpdate:firstViewController.buttonFromFirstView];

    ....
}
```

Within `secondViewController`, you then need to keep a reference to the button that's owned by `firstViewController`. So, something like this in the header file:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton                                    *buttonToUpdate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIButton        *buttonToUpdate;
```

This is a simple answer for a simple question, but to do things "properly", you would probably want to remove the dependency between the two view controllers, and look into using formal or informal protocols.

Also, iOS uses MVC (Model-View-Controller), which would dictate that `SecondViewController` should first send the string from the picker to some Model class that might then notify an observer such as `FirstViewController` that its data has been updated.

Does this make sense or do you need a more full explanation?

Comment: You mentioned a good point about formal/informal protocols.  I come form WEB development background. I am using MVC pattern all the time. The views are NOT dependant on WEB. I would normally use SESSIONS or DB for storing information and passing on to other views. Can I use similar technics, for example using a file to store values, or SQLlite?

Comment: Yep, you can. I don't have experience with SQLite myself, but have a look at Core Data - I believe it can use SQLite for storage.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding" in the WWDC 2011 Session videos: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/. It shows you how to manage a sequence of views (or more precisely view controllers) in iOS, how to send data down to a detail view, and how to get user input or other data back. This video pulls together: (1) how to make the UI without programming, (2) how *UINavigationController* helps the screen flow, and (3) how to pass data back and forward, both using *protocols* and via a *Core Data* database. The parts that directly answer the question start at time 12:00.